# How to iterate through an array outputed in simple_xml_load

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

For example:
[image: img1]

Say I wanted to extract every indices content, no matter the size of the array indices and grab each part like title, description, link?

I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an object, you can get the content like this :

```
$title = $object->title;
$description = $object->description;
$link = $object->link;
$pubDate = $object->pubDate;
```

You can find more informations on Object Oriented Programming here => [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)